# How to kubectl apply by auto deleting?

Tags: kubernetes

I have to deploy Autoscaler through Yaml file and want to make sure that it applies by auto-deleting if the same name already exists. Is it possible to do this without firing an explicit "kubectl delete" command?

Comment: why do you want the auto delete?  to recreate?

Comment: Yes. To re-create

Answer (score 0):

You can use  kubectl replace.

Please refer to this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#replace) for more information.